# How do I get a certain value from the web

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web

So, immagine we had a website, like pewdiepies YT homepage, https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw. And I wanna write a script, that gives me his sub count. Do I have to use beautiful soup for that?

I know, that it is saved in

yt-formatted-string id="subscriber-count" class="style-scope ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer">84,831,541 subscribers/yt-formatted-string>

I have nothing to do with web-dev, so this is a bunch of gibberish for me. But there must be a way for me to get this value, without beautiful soup, mustnt there be one?

```
import urllib.request
import json
import webbrowser

data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw')
print(data)
```

That is all I have thus far.

Comment: You might want to check on an article such as [this one](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup) to learn how web scraping works with something like requests and beautiful soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is web scraping. A quick Google search clarifies how to approach this. The code you are looking for

```py
import requests
from lxml import html

# Retrieve the web page
data = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw')

# Parse the HTML
tree = html.fromstring(data.content)

# Find the subscriber count in the HTML tree
subscriber_count = tree.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"yt-subscription-button-subscriber-count-branded-horizontal")]/text()')[0]

# Convert to integer
subscriber_count = int(subscriber_count.replace(",",""))

print(subscriber_count)
```

The result at the time of writing: "84851474"

If you want to learn more, you can delve deeper in [web scraping in Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/) and [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like you are trying to do is get the sub count of a specified channel. For this, I would use Google Youtube API as it would be faster and more reliable than web scraping. Below is example code.

1) Get an API key and enable this Library

```
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com
```

2) Get the channel id of a Youtube channel e.g PewDiePie is **UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw**

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/<channel_id>
```

3) Make a GET request to the URL below with the specified parms

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

3b) That will return a JSON response that you need to parse

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/MlIT59Jru-h7AvGc09RB7HQI6qA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#channel",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/a5p-d8soZS1kVL3A3QlzHsJFa44\"",
   "id": "UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "20374094982",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "84859110",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "3744"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

*Example code on getting the sub count of pewdiepies channel*

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=<channel_id>&key=<your_api_key>'

resp = requests.get(url=url)
data = resp.json()

sub_count = data['items'][0]['statistics']['subscriberCount']

print(sub_count)
```